# Data and error from the same graphql field

Tags: kotlin, graphql, ktor, graphql-java

Say I have a class `Foo` that looks like this (Kotlin code):

```
class Foo {
  fun ok(): Boolean = true
  fun notOk(): Boolean = throw IllegalArgumentException("test")
}
```

Now say I have a schema where I define the following:

```
type Query {
  getFoo: Foo!
}

type Foo {
  ok: Boolean!
  notOk: Boolean!
}
```

Assume that `getFoo` is in a resolver somewhere. Now if I do the following query:

```
{
  getFoo {
    ok
    notOk
  }
}
```

The whole thing just fails (as expected), but what I want to achieve is that *only* the `notOk` field should turn up in the `error` part of the response and the `ok` field should turn up as part of the `data` part of the response.

For reference, I am using: https://github.com/excitement-engineer/ktor-graphql along with ktor.

As far as I can understand, I need to make a `DataFetcherExceptionHandler` object, but I don't understand how I can both fulfill the non-erroring fields and the erroring field. Any ideas? All I have achieved so far, is to be able to have errors and data in the same query as long as they are top-level fields.

```
val exceptionHandler = DataFetcherExceptionHandler { handlerParameters ->  
  val exception = handlerParameters.exception
  val sourceLocation = handlerParameters.sourceLocation
  val path = handlerParameters.path
  
  val error = object : GraphQLError {
    override fun getMessage() = exception.message
    override fun getLocations() = mutableListOf(sourceLocation)
    override fun getErrorType() = ErrorType.DataFetchingException
  }
  
  DataFetcherExceptionHandlerResult.newResult().error(error).build()
}
```